# What should be the 'Root folder' name in Flas builder 4.5 if java web application is deployed in the war file?

Tags: apache-flex, deployment, flex4.5, blazeds, jboss6.x

I am trying to develop one simple application using Java, Flex and Blazeds. I am using Flash builder 4.5, blazeds 4 and JBoss 6.

I have created 'Dynamic Web' application in Eclipse, added blazeds related file in WEB-INF/lib and in WEB-INF/flex folder. I have deployed this web application in JBoss using Eclipse, so this application is getting deployed in war file.

Then I tried to create new 'Flex Project' using flash builder 4.5 and I am stuck in 2nd step where we have to configure `Root Folder`, `Root URL` and `Context Root`.

As my java web application is deployed in war, there's no folder to which I can set `Root Folder`.

Does anyone knows what shall we do in this case? Is there any other option?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I like to do is actually place my Flex project inside the Java project, usually with the same name as the Java project but with something like "Client" appended.  But this might be a bit more advanced/complex than you'd like. I tend to rely on Ant somewhat, and I don't check the Blaze/LCDS box when setting up the project.  There are a few other options too - try looking at this site:

http://blogs.infosupport.com/flash-builder-4-the-easiest-way-to-create-a-combined-flex-java-project/